# Symfony bundle allow custom provider

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, vendor

I'm developing a bundle for the community.

My bundle has a service to get some content. I have a folder called *Providers* with some providers and an `AbstractProvider` class. All my providers extends the `AbstractProvider`.

When the developer calls my service's function with a string such as `"my_class"`, I instantiate the class from my providers using this name:

```
<?php
new MyClass();
```

In the *Providers* folder, I have some common providers but I want to allow the developer to add its own providers (extending my `AbstractProvider` class). My service must instantiate this custom provider using the class name.

How can I achieve this goal?

Here is my tree:

```
MyBundle
└── Toto
    └── Providers
        ├── AbstractProvider.php
        ├── ArticleProvider.php
        ├── BlockRubricProvider.php
        ├── CommuniqueProvider.php
        ├── HomepageProvider.php
        ├── OffreurSolutionsProvider.php
        ├── PartenaireProvider.php
        ├── PresseProvider.php
        └── PublicationProvider.php
```

And my service:

```
class MyServiceProvider
{

    public function __construct() { }

    /* $providerName exemple: "my_provider" */
    public function getProvider( $provierName )
    {
        $providerClass = str_replace('_', '', ucwords($contentType->identifier, '_'))."Provider";

        /** @var AbstractProvider $provider */
        $provider = new $providerClass( $provierName );

        return $provider;
    }
}
```

How to allow developers to have their own folder Providers with their providers and allow my service to instantiate it with this system ?

Maybe something like this ?

```
use **\Toto\Providers\*;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not call like `BlockRubricProvider::class` and make a check for the namespace or some other check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use the full callified name? In this case you don't need include any use. You can configure the providers with the configuration bundle like [here](https://github.com/geocoder-php/BazingaGeocoderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#usage) and in your AbstractProvider you can put a abstract method to put a name for the provider that the user use to call it.

I hope can help you